# SQL select two tables with no similar entry and different number of columns

Tags: sql

Context: There's no mutual or similar entries in the two tables and there's different number of columns. The only point in common between those tables is: table 2 as table 1 as foreign key.

```
SELECT username, email 
FROM `table1`;

SELECT * 
FROM `table2` 
WHERE username = 'user1';
```

I would like a result that looks like this:

username: 'name', email:'anyemail@email.com'.    (table 1)
column1: 'value', column2: number, column3: 'value', column4, column5 etc.  (table 2).

Is there a way to collect those information in one single call for the database? I did try to play with UNION and one single SELECT but it does not work in that case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

UNION should work.

For the missing columns in table one you should enter NULL values with a Column name.

```
SELECT username, email, NULL as Column3 
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT column1, column2, column3 
FROM Table2
```

Or try also to convert the datatypes, so that they match.

```
SELECT CAST(username AS NVARCHAR(255) AS username, CAST(email AS NVARCHAR(255) AS email, CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(255) AS Column3
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(column1 AS NVARCHAR(255) AS username, CAST(column2 AS NVARCHAR(255) AS email, CAST(column3 AS NVARCHAR(255) AS Column3
FROM Table2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work in my case. When I use union as you mentioned, I get this result =>
 username:henry,   email:  j.s@dd.fr,     column3: null
(column 1 and column 2 of table2 are not returned and I need them as well). But I guess is because UNION work when there is some similarities.

Comment: Yes.
This is the real query that I used in mysql => 
SELECT email, course, name, surname, NULL as unit_5 FROM account where id=90 UNION ALL SELECT unit_1, unit_2, unit_3, unit_4, unit_5 FROM cet where account_id=90;
 And this is the return =>  email:nab@hotmail.com, course:cet, name: nabil, surname: sas, unit_5: null
As you can notice unit_1 etc are not returned. Thank your for your investigation and suggestion.

Comment: And what does the second query has a result, when you execute it separately?

Comment: My second guess is, that the datatypes must be declared. At least for the second table, so that they match and must not be converted implicitly.

SELECT CAST(unit_1 AS NVARCHAR(150)) AS username, ...

Comment: It returns the result as expected for each query. But the thing is from my backend I have to make two calls.

Comment: What about the data type conversion?

Comment: It doesn't work. Even the conversion is not the issue in my real case as they are all of the same type: string. I have tried to replace NULL to ' ' as unit_5 but same result.

Comment: How do you send the command? 
Directly on the database or via a program code?

Comment: On the database, thank you for the time spending.

Comment: What do you mean by "But the thing is from my backend I have to make two calls."?

Comment: To get those informations, I have to to query the database two times from nodeJS:
callDataBase(select name, username from table 1;) => return name, username
callDataBase(select * from table 2;) => return all columns.
(When u ask how I send the command, I said database as I am testing sql through workbench)

Comment: Have you found any reason or solution?

Comment: The only thing that comes up for now is that SQL is a relational database which requires as it is said a 'relation'. Like having the same number of columns (etc) when you target multi tables within one query. You have some little tricks but my case would require too much which is not timeworth. If someone face those issues many times may be a non relational database would be better. Just take my answer as an idea as I am not an expert.

Answer (score 0):

Try a temporary table:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Insert the results of the queries and make a SELECT request.